# "Could not create parent directory for lock file" when compiling Android gradle script

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I encountered errors with Android Studio worked worse, such as when adding dependencies in gradle files. So I reinstalled, and everything worked up to the point where I finished the project. However, I get this error when compiling:

> Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\wrapper\dists\gradle- 8.1.1-bin\9wiye5v2saajue4irfo8ybqfp\gradle-8.1.1-bin.zip.lck

Reinstalling Android and Java didn't help. What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Your environment is severely misconfigured, because those files should not be written to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20`, but to `C:\Users\<yourusername>\.gradle`

Comment: How can i fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea what could cause Gradle to write in the Java installation directory instead of your user profile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to give permission to gradle. Run the below command (put your actual gradle path in `<path_to_gradle>`)

```
chmod ugo+rwx <path_to_gradle>
```

If the above one does not work then run Android Studio as an Administrator.

Comment: The first one didn't work, but launching Android Studio as an administrator indeed solved all the issues. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Windows does not have `chmod`, and it is also not the right solution (neither is running Android Studio as Administrator, BTW).